# Migrating local storage from Cordova to Xamarin App

Tags: cordova, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, cordova-plugins

We are planning on moving our app (iOS, Android, WP) from Cordova/Ionic to Xamarin.

The basic plan is to rebuild everything in Xamarin, keep the same appids in the stores and just provide the new app as "an update".

Now the tricky part. Today our users are signed in via a token stored on the device using `window.localStorage.setItem`in Cordova.

How do I get access to this data in Xamarin? Is it stored somewhere in a file I can look for at startup and do a conversion? What is the format? Is it plaintext or encrypted?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Why not simply request the users to log in once more? You can mention it in your release notes. I'm concerned that what you're trying to achieve could potentially expose a security flaw.

Comment: This really depends on what exactly Cordova's `localStorage` is doing. I tried digging a bit and on iOS it seems to use the local browser storage through WebKit. I can't seem to find the equivalent code for Android or Windows.

Comment: @Demitrian I don't what them to sign in again because our users probably can't remember their password and then they would flood our support. And can you please enlighten me on which kind of security flaw you see in migrating data that is already stored on the device/app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some more research I figured out that localStorage in Cordova is not persistent at all.

For more info look at these:

- [Don't Assume localStorage Will Always Work In Your Hybrid App](http://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/)
- [(iOS)(Cordova) localStorage can get unexpectedly cleared when device storage is low](https://github.com/scottjehl/Device-Bugs/issues/64)

So as I needed to fix this strange bug anyway in my Cordova app, I decided to "move" the token to disk in Cordova by using the [Cordova File Plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file) and now the content of localStorage is "just a file on disk".

By doing this, I effectively answered my own question on how to "migrate data from localStorage" ;)

I hope this may help someone in the same situation.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. Did you find any other way of doing it? Also can you point me to the Xamarin code on how to access the localStorage if I move the token to disk using cordova file plugin?